# VB6 function AscB equivalent in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to use some VB6 code in a .net app. It uses a function AscB which is no longer availiable. What would I need to use in .net?

Extract of how the function is used (function in third line from end)....

```
' Combine each block of 4 bytes (ascii code of character) into one long
' value and store in the message. The high-order (most significant) bit of
' each byte is listed first. However, the low-order (least significant) byte
' is given first in each word.
lBytePosition = 0
lByteCount = 0
Do Until lByteCount >= lMessageLength
    ' Each word is 4 bytes
    lWordCount = lByteCount \ BYTES_TO_A_WORD

    ' The bytes are put in the word from the right most edge
    lBytePosition = (lByteCount Mod BYTES_TO_A_WORD) * BITS_TO_A_BYTE
    lWordArray(lWordCount) = lWordArray(lWordCount) Or _
        LShift(AscB(Mid(sMessage, lByteCount + 1, 1)), lBytePosition)
    lByteCount = lByteCount + 1
Loop
```

Thanks

Comment: That VB6 code looks odd. I'm surprised it isn't AscB(MidB rather than AscB(Mid. [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445073(v=vs.60).aspx). What does the sMessage string contain? Is this running on a double-byte code page like Chinese or Korean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gent, many thanks for your replies... The code I had was part of an MD5 encryption class written in VB6. Over the weekend I came across a .net class I was unaware of... System.Security.Cryptography which gave me the encryption I needed in 5 lines of code instead of the 100+ lines of VB6 code. Many thanks for your efforts.

BTW both your answers worked. Albeit I needed to tweak the VB6 code a bit more.

Comment: you should mark one of the answers given as an answer because this answer doesn't actually answer the question you posted. Your answer should be added onto the bottom of your existing question.

Answer (score 3):

The AscB function pertains only to 8 byte strings.  However, you can (probably) get around it by writing your own function.

```
Public Function AscB (value as Char) as Byte
    return System.Convert.ToByte(value)
End Function
```

Comment: VB6 AscB returns a Byte not a Integer, so your function is not equivalent

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN Library:

The **AscB** function is used with byte data contained in a string.

Instead of returning the character code for the first character, **AscB** returns the first byte

So the following should work:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value).First
```

Where value is a `Char`

Comment: Here's a link to that MSDN topic you've quoted [Asc and AscB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262678(v=vs.60).aspx) and this is [Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx)